# Export data to text file with fixed length records

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I am using MYSQL, WinForms and c#

I have a requirement when I next to get data from my database and export to a text file but each entry needs to be a specific length regardless of the information the database brings in -where data is less than total amount required, empty spaces are to follow it.

E.g First Name could bring in Sam or Samatha but I need to export to be 8 characters in length
"Sam     " (8 total characters)
"Samatha  "(8 total characters)

this is the function that I am using - any help would be greatly appreciated

```
public MySqlDataReader RunQueryTextFile(string query, string s1,string pathName)
{
    MySqlConnection conDataBase = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    MySqlCommand cmdDatabase = new MySqlCommand(query, conDataBase);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@pathName);
    conDataBase.Open();

    myReader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader();
    while (myReader.Read())
    { 
        sw.WriteLine (myReader[s1].ToString());
    }

    sw.Close();
    conDataBase.Close();
    return myReader;
}
```

Comment: I see no attempt to handle your requirement in your current code. Do you have any specific snippets of your attempts?

Comment: `string.PadRight`...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36f2hz3a(v=vs.110).aspx What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use PadRight

```
int totalLength = 8;
myString.PadRight(totalLength, " ").
```

Comment: *each entry needs to be a specific length regardless of the information the database brings in* - Your code doesn't meet this.

Comment: @jdphenix I think it meets the requirement and that's exactly what op needs.

Comment: @imlokesh If a string must be a specific length, for example 8, then `"Christopher".PadRight(8)` returns itself, which is 11 characters long.

Comment: @jdphenix i agree, but instead of downvoting you could have pointed out the problem as even you realise its an easy fix with ‘myString.Substring(0, 8)’

Comment: that is the part I needed help with :) - the padRight answer above did the trick. Thank you i3lai3la you saved me a lot of time.  The only thing I need to do was use a declare a Char and use that instead of just using the "  " .  Thanks Again i3lai3la

Answer (score 0):

You trying to write procedural code. Think objects. I would do something like this

```
// create enum - how to pad
public enum PadStyle    
{
    Right
    Left
}
// create attribute class
public class PaddingAttribute : Attribute
{
     public int TotalLen {get;set;}
     public PadStyle Style {get;set;}
     public char PadChar {get;set;}
     public int Order {get;set;}
}


// Create class record base - this one knows how to get properties, read attributes and pad values into one string
public class RecordBase
{
     protected string CreateRecordProtected()
     {
         // here you 
         // 1 - use reflection to get properties
         // 2 - use reflection to read PaddingAttribute from properties
         // 3 - pad property values using data in PaddingAttribute
         // 4 - concatenate record 
         // something like
         var result = o.GetPropeties().Where(...).Select(...padding logic...);
         return string.Join("", result);
         // padding logic = string.PadRight or string.PadLeft
     }
}
```

[Read here how to deal with attribute classes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_attributes.htm)

```
// Create class record - this one corresponds to your DB
public class Record : RecordBase
{
     private const string _fn_FiedName = "firstName";
     private const string _ln_FiedName = "lastName";

     public Record(IDataReader r)
     {
         FirstName = r[_fn_FiedName];
         LastName = r[_ln_FiedName];
     }

     [Padding(TotalLen = 15, Style = PadStyle.Right, PadChar = " ",  Order = 1)]
     public string FirstName{get;set;}
     [Padding(TotalLen = 20, Style = PadStyle.Right, PadChar = " ",  Order = 2)]
     public string LastName {get;set;}

     public override string ToString()
     {
         return base.CreateRecordProtected();
     }
```

And now, your code with some mods

```
var recList = new List<Record>();
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var reader = cmdDatabase.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            { 
                recList.Add(new Record(reader));
            }
        }
    }
    conn.Close();
} 

if (!recList.Any()) // System.Linq
    return;
IEnumerable<string> textFileRecords = recList.Select(x => x.ToString());
File.WriteAllLines(pathName, textFileRecords); // System.IO
```

Now, you have some decent reusable code.
NOTE: if data amount is huge, you can append right in while

```
var rec = new Record(reader);
rec.ToString() // append this
```

Comment: very details answer,  really appreciate your time :)

Comment: What are you going to do if your record format changes tomorrow? This code will make that change easy